# Solve permission-denied with firebase rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have 3 Firestore collections, Invoices, Clients, and Infos. I wrote the following rule to allow read and write in Firestore only if the user is authenticated.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
}
```

I want to apply this rule only to the `Invoices` and `Clients` collections. For `Infos`, everyone should be able to read and write from the collection without authentication. I tried to change the rule as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
  }
 }
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /Infos {
  allow read, write: if true;
  }
 }
}
```

But I still get a permission denied error when I try to read data from `Infos` without being authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

The following rules should do the trick:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Infos/{infoId} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
    match /Invoices/{invoiceId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /Clients/{clientId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

For the `Invoices` and `Clients` collection, the users you'll be able to read and write into the documents **only** if they are authenticated, while for the `Infos` collection, everybody will be able to do that, no matter if it's authenticated or not.

Comment: Hey keviinlk. Can I help you with other information?